# android.os.DeadSystemException by GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.getRemoteContext

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services, google-ads-api

The production instance of my android app has been crashing. The stack trace isn't much useful. The crash may be coming off of `com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.getRemoteContext` but it may not be the ultimate culprit. Pasting the stack trace below:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
       at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:746)
       at android.app.LoadedApk.access$100(LoadedApk.java:99)
       at android.app.LoadedApk$SplitDependencyLoaderImpl.constructSplit(LoadedApk.java:597)
       at android.content.pm.split.SplitDependencyLoader.loadDependenciesForSplit(SplitDependencyLoader.java:70)
       at android.app.LoadedApk$SplitDependencyLoaderImpl.ensureSplitLoaded(LoadedApk.java:632)
       at android.app.LoadedApk$SplitDependencyLoaderImpl.getSplitPathsForSplit(LoadedApk.java:641)
       at android.app.LoadedApk.getSplitPaths(LoadedApk.java:658)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.createResources(ContextImpl.java:2152)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContextAsUser(ContextImpl.java:2214)
       at android.app.ContextImpl.createPackageContext(ContextImpl.java:2193)
       at android.content.ContextWrapper.createPackageContext(ContextWrapper.java:884)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.getRemoteContext(GooglePlayServicesUtilLight.java:125)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabl.initialize(zzabl.java:23)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabp.zzi(zzabp.java:15)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabo.get(zzabo.java:11)
       at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.zzbr.zza(zzbr.java:13)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzabp.initialize(zzabp.java:1)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzamy.run(zzamy.java:2)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Please take a look and let me know if any more details are required to be shared. I am using the following dependencies for google ads API:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'
implementation group: 'com.github.ankitbatra11', name: 'billboard', version: '2.0.1'
implementation group: 'com.google.ads.mediation', name: 'facebook', version: '6.2.0.1'
implementation group: 'com.google.ads.mediation', name: 'adcolony', version: '4.4.0.0'
```

Comment: Did you find the cause for the exception?